Defining the base for a matrix A and relation with rank
I am a little bit confused with linear algebra definitions:
I know that for a matrix A:

The rank is the maximum number of linear independent column vectors

I also know that for a vector space, a base is a minimal set of vectors s.t any other vector can be written as a linear combination of those. But I have seen the word base being used also for linear systems of equations and the associated matrix. So for a matrix a base I think (I could not find a definition specifically for matrices):

is a maximal set of indices that correspond to linearly independent
columns of A

So my question is : Is the rank(A) the same as the cardinality of a base?
So for example if A is an $m \times n$ matrix and rank(A) =n then the base has to be unique (it is all the indices). Right/wrong?
